# How to make objects attract/stick to a single object

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

I'm kinda new to blender been using it for a little while now,but was wondering how I could make objects attract/stick to an object (one single object) i have that will be the center of a giant ball of junk im making. would the magnetic force field work? I'm going for a result to the video game Katamari damacy

Comment: Yes Force Field with a negative Strength value seems like a good idea

Comment: thank you for the help 